# shortening form validation jQuery code

Tags: jquery

I have written this code, and it works just find, but I feel like I'm being very stupid here and that I could shorten this code. Is there anyway to shorten this?
Please leave it as the answer, thank you.

```
$('.submit-form').on('click' , function() {

 if($('.form-signup1').val().length === 0) {
   $('.form-signup1').addClass('error')
 }

 if($('.form-signup2').val().length === 0) {
   $('.form-signup2').addClass('error')
 }

 if($('.form-signup3').val().length === 0) {
   $('.form-signup3').addClass('error')
 }

 if($('.form-signup4').val().length === 0) {
   $('.form-signup4').addClass('error')
 }

 if($('.form-signup5').val().length === 0) {
   $('.form-signup5').addClass('error')
 }

 if($('.form-signup6').val().length === 0) {
   $('.form-signup6').addClass('error')
 }

});
```

EDIT: Thank you all so much for your answers, I really do appreciate your time. I chose the one that I could understand best. Thanks again!

Comment: can you provide the html too, so it will be much more easier

Comment: .form-signup classes are input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a common class to all elements then

```
$('.submit-form').on('click', function () {
    $('.form-signup').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);

        if ($this.val().length === 0) {
            $this.addClass('error');
        }
    })

});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can't add a new class to your elements use this

```
for (var i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
    var $this = $('.form-signup' + i);
    if ($this.val().length === 0) {
        $this.addClass('error');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $('.submit-form').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var error=0;
        $('input[type=text]').each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            error++;
            if ($this.val().length === 0) {
                $this.addClass('error');
            }
        });
   if(error==0)
   $("form")[0].submit();

    });
```

Above code will prevent from submitting while error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

If you are validating the value of each input, you could do it like

```
 $('input[type=text]').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val().length === 0) {
            $this.addClass('error');
        }
    })
```